# method convertServiceModel in class steps.FuncionalidadNESteps cannot be applied to given types;

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, cucumber, gherkin

```
public void validarServicioNEProductoPOSTCrearUsuario(List<ServicioModel> table) {

    SoftAssert sa = new SoftAssert();
    ArrayList<String> listResults = new ArrayList<>();



    for (ServicioModel serviceMod : table) {

        System.out.println("===========================================");
        System.out.println("======== (POST) - Crear usuario ===========");
        System.out.println("===========================================");

      String endpoint = serviceMod.getBody();

        Response response = ResponseProyectoNEServices.postUser(serviceMod.getBody(endpoint));
        String strMessageError = CommonServicesUtil.responseMessage(response, serviceMod.getExp());
        sa.assertEquals(response.getStatusCode(), serviceMod.getExp(), "Escenario [" + serviceMod.getEscenario() + "] Message [" + strMessageError + "]");

        listResults.add("[" + serviceMod.getExp() + "][" + serviceMod.getEscenario() + "]");
    }

    System.out.println("================================================");
    System.out.println("================== Resume test =================");
    System.out.println("================================================");

    for (String result : listResults) {
        System.out.println(result);
    }
    sa.assertAll();
}
```

I put the parameter but I don't understand why it shows me an error.

I put the variable endpoint like a parameter, but it doesn't work.